# CSS overrided after opening Modal dialog that loaded external HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a tab wizard in my ASP.NET MVC project and in one of the tab I open a modal dialog by rendering an html retrieved from an external api. However, when closing wizard and go to next tab, the table style (border colour and thickness) in the tab is changed as the style of html in modal dialog. What I have tried so far to force td, th, border style via `!important`, it but does not make so much sense. So, in this scenario, what should I do? I cannot modify the style of the external source that is returned an html with css. I also tried to force its style via JavaScript (set css) after modal closed, but not so much sense. Any idea?

Here is some of my attempt in css and my html page:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, 
.table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857 !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7ecf1 !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}


<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Aaaaaa </th>
            <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Bbbbbbbbb</td>
                <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use Javascript to remove the `<style>` tag containing the externally loaded css

Comment: When should I remove it? After reloaded modal? And how? Because if I remove before loading in this case external document lose its style that is what I do not want. Any example pls?

Comment: After closing the modal I guess. Your issue is that the styling is still there after closing it right? I'll add example code in an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the style of modal still there after closing and even if opening another tab. I am waiting for your reply, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<style>` tag on closing the modal:

```
// call this function on closing the modal
function deleteStyleTag() {
  const styleTag = document.querySelector('.modal style');
  // change selector according to your situation

  // remove the <style> tag
  styleTag.parentElement.removeChild(styleTag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. However, when closing it works. But opening I cannot delete style. The problem is that: when I use open event of modal the method cannot delete style, because at that time the html content has lot loaded yet. When modal loaded the delete method is called but the style under the modal is not changed. I use `$( "#myModal" ).on('loaded.bs.modal', function(){}` and `$( "#myModal" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){}`. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: By the way, just a little question. What if I want to redesign this ugly html using JavaScript? I can detect the parts using "+" signs on that document, but have no idea how to reform using a loop and markings like "+" in this document. Something like stringbuilder, etc. in JavaScript? Any idea?

Comment: Any reply please?